# How to manage Roles in Ckan 2+

Tags: customization, addition, roles, ckan, paster

I've installed CKAN 2.2 and now I try to manage my organizations users and have a coherant workflow so i search how to manage roles (add new ones, what options are avaiable, delete etc.).

On google, I've find a possible way by using the "paster" command but that was only doable for versions 1.9 and less.

I never used an API before and i tried to used the CKAN one, but I do not find in the latest guide a way to do what I want.

I hope you'll help me,

potatoe

Answer (score 1):

CKAN has roles, but they're only relevant in the context of organizations. Inside an organization, there can be a member, editor, and admin. These permissions are fairly fixed and not easily changeable. What is possible is [overriding the auth functions](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/extensions/tutorial.html) to do what you want.

Besides this, there can be sysadmin users on CKAN itself who have all the rights.